# Created SSL certificate on my server, but it is not trusted

Tags: ssl-certificate

I am trying to activate HTTPS for my domain name. Chrome recognizes the SSL certificate when i go to https://www.example.com, but I get the error and it says that my SSL is not trusted. What do I need to do to get my SSL certificate to be trusted?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a self-signed certificate, get one from a certificate provider. I'd recommend you looking at LetsEncrypt because they have a good automated support for being able to renew certificates automatically.